# How to predict Rand() function in C?

Tags: c, algorithm, random

I am trying to make an oracle which predicts next random number in a sequence. I have an array of random generated numbers.

Comment: Please explain how if you are successful it does not mean a bug in the implementation. Or are you thinking of something like Using a constant seed for srand(), recording several rand()s and then starting from scratch? That is not an oracle that is "knowing".

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/31643/how-to-predict-c-rand

Comment: I'm not at all clear about what you're asking.  Are you seeking an algorithm?  Advice?  Knowledge about how `rand()` is implemented?

Answer (score 1):

The `rand()` function is a **Pseudo**-Random Number Generator (PRNG). It is not a [cryptographically secure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) source of entropy. If you know the seed, you can completely predict the sequence as it is deterministic, typically based on [Linear Congruential Generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) (LCG). Such generators have a finite period length, after which they repeat.

If you know the given sequence starts from the beginning, it would be trivial to brute-force the seed to find matching initial sequence. Otherwise there are statistical methods you could use to narrow down the potential seeds.

Comment: this is a lot more accurate than saying you can not predict random numbers, however I don't think it answers this man's question, I've encountered some blogpost before showing how easily a c random could be predicted due to it's low entropy, looking for it as we speak

Comment: Cool, I'm sure someone has done a full analysis of this. If you find the post, please post an answer with the link!

Comment: this is for python, but the concept is the same https://github.com/tna0y/Python-random-module-cracker

Answer (score -1):

If you have actual random numbers, there's no way to predict them.

Software can be programmed to use actual random numbers that are acquired from monitoring random events like background radiation, atomic decay and electrical noise from various components. This is usually used only for critical applications like creating cryptographic keys, since the operation will block until enough "Random bits" have been collected.

Most software uses an algorithm that creates random-looking numbers based on a seed and past events like calls to the PRNG, elapsed time, etc. These are possible to predict with 100 accuracy if you know the algorithm used and all the events it uses for inputs, or have the ability to reset the seed to a known value.

Comment: that's actually not true, you should read a bit more regarding entropy in mathematics, random is a very complicated issue both mathematically and philosophically

Comment: @DrPrItay Which part isn't true? That you can get truly random numbers by monitoring atomic decay events, or that you can get predictable random numbers by resetting the seed to a known value?

Comment: so here comes the philosophical part, who said monitoring atomic decay is random or behaves in a random matter? even path integrals representing the wave functions of particles is treated in some occasions as un-random and just purely statistical, it's all a matter of resolution you're looking at and how you define a random event mathematically, some will say nothing is random, it's all a matter of mathematical resolution 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)

Comment: @DrPrItay your objection is based on ancient philosophical questions that can not be definitively answered. The OP was asking a math-based programming question.

Comment: I agree I come from a somewhat cryptographic background, I've encountered a guy that managed to predict python's random and I've encountered a blog post that does the same for crand(), hence saying you cannot predict these numbers is simply incorrect, I'm looking for that blogpost as we speak

Comment: take a look at this https://github.com/tna0y/Python-random-module-cracker

Comment: @DrPrItay I think you missed the part where I said that PRNGs are predictable.

Comment: Yeah, I definitely haven't noticed your edit, my bad, yet still, your answer is somewhat confusing, reading it first glance, you might immediately deduce that all randoms are unpredictable

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. The only thing I changed was adding the P to RNG, which I had missed. PRNGs are predictable. RNGs based on random physical events aren't.

Comment: Camen about that I also disagree, the question we should all ask, is the universe deterministic or not? can you answer that with a scientific validity behind it? if so be sure to call all leading physicists as you might be able to aid them in governing a theory of everything :D